# Google Colab-ValueError: Mountpoint must be in a directory that exists

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, valueerror

I want to mount google drive on google Colab and I am using this command to mount the drive

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')
```

but I am getting this error

```
ValueError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-9667a744255b> in <module>()
       1 from google.colab import drive
 ----> 2 drive.mount('content/drive/')

 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/colab/drive.py in
 mount(mountpoint, force_remount)
      99       raise ValueError('Mountpoint must either be a directory or not exist')
     100     if '/' in mountpoint and not _os.path.exists(_os.path.dirname(mountpoint)):
 --> 101       raise ValueError('Mountpoint must be in a directory that exists')
     102   except:
     103     d.terminate(force=True)

 ValueError: Mountpoint must be in a directory that exists
```

Comment: drive.mount('/content/drive') does not work anymore for me too since yesterday (January 19). Did Google Colab change something? I have not changed anything on my side and this command has been working for months.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

@clarky: the error you got was correct tried to tell you that your usage of drive.mount() is incorrect: the mountpoint argument to drive.mount() must be an empty directory that exists, or the name of a non-existent file/directory in a directory that does exist so that the mountpoint can be created as part of the mount operation. Your usage of a relative path in `drive.mount('content/drive/')` (i.e. `content/drive/`) implies that the mount should happen at `'/content/content/drive'` because the interpreter's default path is `/content`; note the doubled `content` path component there, and likely you don't already have a directory named /content/content inside of which a mountpoint named `drive` could be created. The fix to your notebook code is to instead use `drive.mount('/content/drive')` - note the leading `/` making the mountpount path absolute instead of relative.

Answer (score 11):

Just go to "manage section" , then terminate your current section, and try to mount again with:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=True)
```

It worked here.

Answer (score 5):

Simply use:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("/content/gdrive")
```

instead of:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("/content/drive/")
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this error this morning as  well. I'm not sure what this [commit](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/commit/eea058dc9573b4fbc34a320ac9e0c8fc57b83d85) what meant to fix but it certainly caused the error. A workaround is to copy the code for [drive.py](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/blob/eea058dc9573b4fbc34a320ac9e0c8fc57b83d85/google/colab/drive.py) into colab, comment out lines `100` and `101` like this:

```
# drive.py

...

  try:
    if _os.path.islink(mountpoint):
      raise ValueError('Mountpoint must not be a symlink')
    if _os.path.isdir(mountpoint) and _os.listdir(mountpoint):
      raise ValueError('Mountpoint must not already contain files')
    if not _os.path.isdir(mountpoint) and _os.path.exists(mountpoint):
      raise ValueError('Mountpoint must either be a directory or not exist')
    #  if '/' in mountpoint and not _os.path.exists(_os.path.dirname(mountpoint)):
    #    raise ValueError('Mountpoint must be in a directory that exists')
  except:
    d.terminate(force=True)
    raise

...
```

then replace

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('content/drive/')
```

with

```
mount('/content/drive/')
```

using the `mount` function you copied from `drive.py`

Hopefully the issue gets fixed quickly enough so we can do away with this workaround.

Comment: I tried using your approach. But the authentication takes forever. Its not working.

Comment: What part of the authentication took forever?

Comment: @Jimi: Your suggestion works because of the replacement of the relative path with an absolute one; the commenting-out is irrelevant.

Comment: @clarky: if you are seeing timeout errors during authentication please chime in on https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/382

Comment: @AmiF Nope. I had ‘/content/drive’ when it failed for me

Comment: @Jimi: if you can still repro can you follow up to https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/382#issuecomment-455275083 ?

Comment: Actually, my bad, I had a trailing '/'.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I click the folder icon on the side panel, it will show you Upload, Refresh and Mount Drive.

1. click on the Mount Drive, the 'drive' folder containing 'My Drive'
   folder appears
2. Then run

   from google.colab import drive
   drive.mount('drive')
3. Go to this URL in a browser will appear - I sign to one of my account
4. Enter your authorization code

[Drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76Crz.png)

Answer (score 1):

I received the error as well change to `drive.mount('/content/drive')`

Answer (score 1):

Replace `drive.mount('/content/drive/')` by `drive.mount('/content/drive')`

Answer (score 1):

just remove the '/' following the drive and it works perfectly..

That is from drive.mount('/content/drive/') to drive.mount('/content/drive')

Comment: can you please explain your answer so OP can understand what is error in his code. thanks

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING: Make sure to read my explanation before running the command below**

I ran into this error today and the reason was that Google Colab for some reason kept some folders and files from the previous session (probably because I created the folders from within the notebook). These files and folders were still being shown via the "Folders" menu, but no other GDrive files were, as I hadn't authenticated again. Even the `"force_remount=True"` option didn't work.

To fix this, I simply deleted the remaining files from `/drive/` by running the following command:

```
! rm -rf drive/
```

Then I could mount my GDrive again on the `/drive/` directory:

```py
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Answer (score 0):

Run command to unmount drive first.

```
!fusermount -u drive
```

Then try run again,

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Comment: FYI instead of hard-coding `fusermount` you should probably use the `force_remount=True` param to `drive.mount()`

Answer (score 0):

If mounting does not work even if absolute path `/content/drive` was used, then verify that appropriate directories exist,

`!mdkir -p /content/drive`

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you haven't mounted the drive previously but had a path that led to saving your data in the drive. So now, as colab doesn't have access to your drive, it will create a directory with the same names as your path and then save it in the colab session. Now, if you want to mount the drive now, it will have issues because the same path is referred but to two different locations.
Easy fix for this is to:
a.) Delete the files from your sessions in the colab
or
b.) Rename drive named folder in your colab session.
Now try to mount again. You should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

**You indicated you typed the right command**

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')
```

Read the -----> it indicates you that what ever you typed during the time of your code snippet, line 2 has the error and its not your code you mentioned. the / needed to be there before the word content. Good luck.

```
ValueError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-9667a744255b> in <module>()
       1 from google.colab import drive
 ----> 2 drive.mount('content/drive/')
```