# colab research python can not connect to the gdrive

Tags: connection, google-colaboratory

I was trying to connect to the gdrive in my colab research ipython. But today in the morning when I wrote this code,

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')
```

It throws me an error code;

```
ValueError: Mountpoint must be in a directory that exists
```

[image: gdrive]

I can not connect to the gdrive, what might be the reason?
Thank you

Comment: I answered the same question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54232739/2826013

Answer (score 0):

The actual fix is not the addition of `force_remount=True` but rather dropping the trailing `/` in the arg to `drive.mount()`.

Answer (score -1):

Actually I got the answer.
İnstead

```
 from google.colab import drive
 drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Below needs to be typed

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=True)
```

Thank you