# Save TensorFlow checkpoint in a Google Colab

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to save my trained model using a [TF.train.Saver()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver)

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  [...]
  save_path = saver.save(sess, "/final_model.ckpt")
```

I know this works on a local computer, but when I'm trying to run it on a Google Colab, it does not and gives me the following error:

> ValueError: Parent directory of final_model.ckpt doesn't exist

I have performed the answer proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54230871/google-colab-valueerror-mountpoint-must-be-in-a-directory-that-exists),

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive/')
```

but my saved model will not be placed in the current directory. It goes into `content` folder where I do not see in My Drive.

My code is under `My Drive/TF 01/some method/` and I would like to save the checkpoints and logs in the same folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because of the line:

```
save_path = saver.save(sess, "/final_model.ckpt")
```

The " / " symbol refers to "home" of Colab. Assuming that your personal drive is mounted as:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive/')
```

You can save in your drive in this way:

```
save_path = saver.save(sess, "gdrive/My Drive/TF 01/some method/final_model.ckpt")
```

Or by hard coding:

```
save_path = saver.save(sess, "/content/gdrive/My Drive/TF 01/some method/final_model.ckpt")
```

Or, if you just want It in your runtime, just remove the " / " symbol:

```
save_path = saver.save(sess, "final_model.ckpt")
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "if you just want in your runtime, just remove the / symbol". Where does it get saved if I remove "/"? Can't I find it later and after the work is done?

Comment: It means that It Will be saved in your runtime, in the folder "/content/". Basically, It is the "file explorer" that you see on the left when you open a colaboratory page. If you save a file in this way in Colab, you Will lose It when you are resetting the runtime. That's why i also suggested you to save it in the Google drive folder, so that you Will not lose model weights resetting the runtime.

Comment: Is there a way to get the current directory without having to hard-code it? I don't like to share my file structure (i.e., `"/content/gdrive/My Drive/TF 01/some method/final_model.ckpt"`) when sharing my colab.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible. The only thing you can do is to use the syntax `gdrive/My Drive/TF 01/some method/final_model.ckpt` instead of the one with `/content/` , but you can't hide your google drive structure.

Comment: @mao95 Do we just make up our own syntax for /TF 01/ or is that standard? And could I get an example of what to put in place of "/some method/". Thanks 
MatinKh Kh for asking this.